# Is this angular select2 example some kind of sorcery or what?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-select2

I am looking at this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qQ228YE3AkcdDIwZESsm?p=preview) and I can't believe it. You can see that if person with name matching search string exists in `people` array that person is shown in dropdown and otherwise it suggests to create a new one which this `(new)` string indicates. But how does it decide what element to show? It seems these two conditionally shown/hidden divs are responsible for it, right?

```
<div ng-if="person.isTag" ng-bind-html="person.name +' <small>(new)</small>'| highlight: $select.search"></div>
<div ng-if="!person.isTag" ng-bind-html="person.name + person.isTag| highlight: $select.search"></div>
```

But wait, what is this?? Person objects don't have isTag property, or do they? I can't see it in `demo.js`. **How does this even work? Where this mysterious `isTag` flag is coming from?** Please, I think I'm going crazy.

And also, why concatenate `person.name` with boolean (it is boolean I assume) value `person.isTag`? By the way this example is forked the one that I found on angularjs select2 documentation page, I just stripped all other examples.
[this is original plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/m1SQXUxftBLQtitng1f0)

[image]

Comment: i'm guessing the library adds that property.

Comment: well I didn't find any mention of it in library source and that doesn't seem to work when I try to do the same in my project

Comment: You don't see an "isTag" property on the objects because *there isn't one*. That's what the code is checking. If you add `isTag: true` to one of those "person" objects, you'll see that the selection is rendered with that `(new)` marker instead.

Comment: @Pointy then how come the first item in dropdown redners with this `(new)` word? How come it has this `isTag` property? Who put it in there?

Comment: @dKab, I didn't see `(new)` rendered for any object, until you add it.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the meaning of that is, but looking at stuff like that makes me glad I'm not using Angular :)

Comment: @Pointy try typing name which doesn't present in the list

Answer (score 1):

***If*** the `person` object has `isTag`, then it renders the name with the `"(new)"` suffix.

The template basically defines how to render an object with the `isTag` property, and without.

The first template - the rendering of which is controlled by `ng-if="person.isTag"` - is rendered when `isTag` property is defined and truthy.

The `isTag` refers to the property of the `person` object as defined by:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="person in people">
```

Comment: Yes I understand that. But where is this property coming from?

Comment: @dKab, it comes from the `person` object - if it is defined there. Try adding it to one of the objects in `$scope.people`.

Comment: @dKab See what happens when you go into `demo.js` and manually add `isTag: true` to one of the objects!

Comment: @Pointy Ok, If I add it manually it works as expected, but in demo.js there is no mention of it. You see my point?

Comment: @dKab oh yes, I understand why it's confusing.

Comment: That is **very** confusing to say least. I still haven't got an answer to my question.

Comment: @dKab, what is the question? Wasn't it "what is this `isTag`"?

Comment: @NewDev the question is: **How come the first item in dropdown renders with `(new)` word**? Who add this `isTag` property to it? Where is the code which does that?

Comment: @dKab, Perhaps you have polluted your plunker... When I go to your plunker in a fresh browser window, there is no `"(new)"` in the first item: http://plnkr.co/edit/qQ228YE3AkcdDIwZESsm?p=preview

Comment: I know what ng-if does thank you but apparently you misunderstood my question

Comment: @NewDev what do you mean by polluted? Could you fork it and unpollute? What does it render when you typing random gibberish into input? Could you attach screenshot, please?

Comment: @dKab, I mean that if I go to the plunker that you posted (url of which I re-posted in the comment above) - in a fresh browser window (i.e. without modifications to the code) - and scrolling through the select choices, or typing, I don't see on the first item (or anywhere else) the `(new)` suffix. If I type gibberish - and no name is matched - then it hides the drop-down.

Comment: @NewDev tried open in new incognito window still see it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73610/discussion-between-new-dev-and-dkab).

Answer (score 1):

The `isTag` property is coming from the `$select.searchInput.on('keyup', function(e) {` in the `SelectMultipleDirective`.  Note that if you remove `multiple` from your code, this property is never set.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/src/uiSelectMultipleDirective.js#L252

Comment: I didn't even see the `(new)` - and still not sure why the OP saw it - since there is no `multiple` set in the plunker he shared (that I see)

Comment: I suspect he was messing with the model, got a `(new)` entry in the list, before removing the `multiple` tag.  Plunker doesn't retroactively rebuild your data when you modify live code, so he could be left with random data, but it would be gone on a browser refresh....

Comment: I swear, I created a new plunker with the code, and the OP still saw `(new)` :)